# opengl shader directional lights specular reflection increasing with distance

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, specular

the title says it all.. using opengls built in lighting system, specularlight does not increase or decrease with distance from the object, but by shader implementation does.

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;

out vec2 texCoord0;
out vec3 normal0;
out vec3 worldPos0;

uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 normalRotation;
uniform mat4 transformProjected;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = transformProjected * vec4(position, 1.0);
    texCoord0 = texCoord;

    normal0 = normalize((normalRotation * vec4(normal, 0.0))).xyz;
    worldPos0 = (transform * vec4(position, 1.0)).xyz; 
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330

in vec2 texCoord0;
in vec3 normal0;
in vec3 worldPos0;

out vec4 fragColor;

struct BaseLight
{
    vec3 colorDiffuse;
    vec3 colorSpecular;
    float intensityDiffuse;
};
struct DirectionalLight
{
    BaseLight base;
    vec3 direction;
};

uniform vec3 tint;
uniform sampler2D sampler;

uniform vec3 eyePos; // camera pos

uniform vec3 ambientLight;
uniform vec3 emissiveLight;

//material 
uniform float specularIntensity;
uniform float specularPower;

uniform DirectionalLight directionalLight;

vec4 calcLight(BaseLight base,vec3 direction, vec3 normal)
{
    float diffuseFactor = dot(normal, -direction);

    vec4 diffuseColorFinal = vec4(0,0,0,0);
    vec4 specularColorFinal = vec4(0,0,0,0);

    if(diffuseFactor > 0)
    {
      diffuseColorFinal =  vec4(base.colorDiffuse,1) * diffuseFactor * base.intensityDiffuse;

      vec3 directionToEye = normalize(eyePos - worldPos0);
      vec3 reflectDirection = normalize(reflect(direction, normal));

      float specularFactor = dot(directionToEye, reflectDirection);
      specularFactor = pow(specularFactor, specularPower);

      if(specularFactor > 0)
          specularColorFinal = vec4(base.colorSpecular,1) * specularFactor   * specularIntensity;
    }
    //
   return diffuseColorFinal + specularColorFinal;
}



void main()
{
    vec4 colorD = texture(sampler, texCoord0.xy) * vec4(tint,1);
    vec3 normal = normal0;
    vec4 totalLight = vec4(ambientLight,1) + vec4(emissiveLight,1); 

     totalLight += calcLight(directionalLight.base,-directionalLight.direction,normal);


    fragColor = colorD * totalLight;
}
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see from the 2 images the specular light takes up a larger surface area the farther the camera gets from the plane.In my test with opengls built in lighting, this doesnt happen. is there a way to fix this? im new to lighting, maybe this is normal for directional light sources? thanks for the help!

Im also setting my eyePos uniform to my cameraPos. i dont know if that helps.

Comment: This has happened to me before, but I assumed it was because the surface is completely flat. I could be wrong, but I think the angles from the camera position to each fragment have decreased and the resulting surface colour from your fragment shader is now almost completely in the specular range. I don't know if I've explained it clearly though. I know what I mean in my head, just not how to explain very well. I found looking at some BRDF related things online and the [Real-Time Rendering](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Real_time_Rendering.html?id=zMAFmQEACAAJ&redir_esc=y) book helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to have distance between the fragment and the light `dist` . This can be a problem for directional light though because you have only the direction and distant is assumed to be infinite. Maybe switch to point light?

when youo have the 'dist' you use a formula

```
att = 1.0 / (Kc + Kl*dist + Kq*dist^2)
Kc - constant attenuation
Kl - linear attenuation
Kq - quadratic attenuation
```

simpler version (only Kq used, rest set to 1.0):

```
float attenuation = 1.0 / (1.0 + light.attenuation * pow(distanceToLight, 2));
```

then in the lighting equation you basically multiply calculated color by this `att` factor:

```
vec4 finalColor = ambient + (diffuseColorFinal + specularColorFinal)*att
```

http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/glsl_lighting_phong_p4.php#part_4

http://tomdalling.com/blog/modern-opengl/07-more-lighting-ambient-specular-attenuation-gamma/